# Way to get mozInnerScreenY in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

How do I get the coordinates of the top left pixel of document body in Chrome? In firefox it's possible to get with `window.mozInnerScreenY` + `window.window.mozInnerScreenX`, but not so much in Chrome?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.screenY` is the standard property. It works everywhere.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/screenY

If your code runs inside an iFrame it will still return the top screenY position and not the iFrame/viewport one.

Now, to measure what you are describing below (sorry, I misunderstood you) all that needs to be done is subtract the innerHeight from the outerHeight (that's give you the size of the chrome/toolbars and so, and add the screenY (which gives you the top pixel of the Chrome app, as you said).

Wrapping up, this does the trick:

`window.screenY + window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight`

[body top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyZkV.png)

Comment: It returns the screenY of the chrome app, not the document.body

Comment: You are right. I misunderstood the question. But there it goes, I've just edited the previous answer