Is there an equivalent to mozInnerScreenX and mozInnerScreenY in Chrome that works in iframes?
In Firefox, you can use mozInnerScreenX and mozInnerScreenY properties to get the screen coordinates of the upper-left corner of the current viewport. This also works for code that is executing in the context of an iframe, in that it will return the screen coordinates of the upper-left corner of the iframe's visible area on screen.
However, mozInnerScreenX, and mozInnerScreenY are non-standard and only work in Firefox. Is there a way to do the same thing in Chrome?

Same unanswered yet, but worth checking later https://stackoverflow.com/q/72182336/10141885

Unfortunately I found no direct way to get that information. But it is possible to calculate it, though it takes some effort.
My method was to have the top-level frame on the page calculate its left and top coordinates using the formula:
innerScreenLeft = window.screenX + (window.outerWidth - window.innerWidth) * 0.5
innerScreenTop = window.screenY + window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight

This is really just a guess, and assumes that there's nothing to the left, right, or bottom of the window's content area. (So only a URL bar, tab bar, and such on top). So if the user opens, for example, the developer tools along the left, right, or bottom of the window, the calculation will be incorrect. Unfortunately I haven't found any way around this.
Then I have the top level frame iterate over all of its iframes and send them the screen coordinates of their left and top edge by calling the iframe's getBoundingClientRect method and adding their parent frame's top and left coordinate to that, and repeat that recursively for every frame.
This wouldn't be too hard to do using window.postMessage, but because any script running on the page would receive those messages and they could possibly cause interference, I wanted to keep that to a minimum and use chrome.runtime.sendMessage as much as possible.
The trick to doing that was figuring out the document ID of each iframe. To do so, I had my content script run in every frame, i.e. all_frames = true in manifest.json, and then had them do the following:

On load, use chrome.runtime.sendMessage to send a message to the background script, and then have it send back a response containing the event sender's document ID, so that each content script can learn its document ID

Check to see if the content script is running in an iframe (i.e. check if window.self !== window.top) and then use window.parent.postMessage to send the frame's document ID to its parent frame. This is the only time I use window.postMessage

Each parent frame receives that message and tracks which iframe corresponds to which document ID by finding the iframe whose contentWindow is equal to the message event's source property

At this point, and every time the page scrolls, the parent frame iterates over all of its iframes, and then sends an "update top-left" message to the background script, once for each iframe, with the message containing the document ID of the frame being updated and its newly calculated screen left and screen top.

The background script receives the "update top-left" message and then bounces it to the content script that corresponds to the document ID in the message

The client script receives the "update top-left" message and then holds on to its new screen left and top coordinate


It's an annoying amount of work to do this, especially given the method isn't even guaranteed to calculate the right coordinates, but it does seem to work for the most part so long as the top-most frame calculates its screen left and top correctly.
Hopefully at some point Chrome will just add something equivalent to mozInnerScreenX and mozInnerScreenY. In Firefox, absolutely none of this is necessary, and those two values just give you exactly what you want.
